# What is the level cap in Final Fantasy XV Pocket Edition?

Tags: final-fantasy-15-pocket-edition

The level cap for Final Fantasy XV was increased from 99 to 120 post launch. Was this change carried over to Pocket Edition or is the level cap still 99 in that game? Also, is the level cap even reachable due to the reduced scope of the game?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the level cap in Final Fantasy 15 is level 120. To reach it you’ll need somewhere in the region of 25-27 million EXP

### SOURCE

[1]https://www.vg247.com/2018/03/07/final-fantasy-15-guide-how-to-level-up-quickly-reach-level-cap/

Comment: That is for the standard version of FFXV, not the pocket edition